# In Postgres, what does pg_stat_database.xact_commit actually mean?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to understand `SELECT xact_commit FROM pg_stat_database;`  According to docs, it is "Number of transactions in this database that have been committed".  But I turned on logging all queries (`log_min_duration = 0`) and it seems there are other things besides that can affect `xact_commit` than just a query.  For example, connecting a `psql` client or typing `BEGIN;`  will increase it by various values.  There is a step in my application that runs a single query (as confirmed by the log), but consistently increases the counter by 15-20.  Does anyone know anything more specific about what is counted in `xact_commit`, or if there is a way to count only actual queries?

Comment: This article http://okigiveup.net/what-postgresql-tells-you-about-its-performance/ can help you with that!

Comment: Thanks!  It doesn't address the question about "xact_commit", but at least it shows a way queries can be counted.  After enabling the query statistics, I can run "select sum(calls) from pg_stat_statements".

Answer (score 6):

`pg_stat_database.xact_commit` really is the number of commits in the database (remember that every statement that is not run in a transaction block actually runs in its own little transaction, so it will cause a commit).

The mystery that remains to be solved is why you see more commits than statements, which seems quite impossible (For example, `BEGIN` *starts* a transaction, so by definition it cannot increase `xact_commit`).

The solution is probably that database activity statistics are collected asynchronously: they are sent to the *statistics collector process* via an UDP socket, and the statistics collector eventually updates the statistics.

So my guess is that the increased transaction count you see is actually from earlier activities.

Try keeping the database absolutely idle for a while and then try again, then you should see a slower increase.

Comment: I see; thanks for that information.  I have log_min_duration_statement = 0 in postgresql.conf

Comment: I think maybe something is happening in the background, as the counter seems to increase when I leave it for a while.  But I can't figure out what that might be.  I'm running postgres locally and don't have any applications connected to it that I know of.

Comment: Does  the work autovacuum does count as a transaction (i.e. the update to the system catalogs)?

Comment: @JonathanCrosmer I have completely revised my answer as I think I know now what is going on.

Comment: I tried leaving the database idle, then querying for "xact_commit", but it has mysteriously increased by about 40 in roughly half an hour.